# Setting a durable pin-mark in maps by using Siri

Tags: iphone, ios, siri

It's possible saying to Siri: "Show me my current location". Then it opens maps and marks the current position there.

One can then setting a persistent mark by using touch-screen.

Now I ask myself: 
Is it possible to set this pin via Siri?

Or more precise: It there a command for saying "Hey Siri. Mark my current position in maps durable!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is not achievable via Siri, but you can still use Siri and a couple of taps to get what you're asking for.

## "Hey Siri, where am I?"

All you have to do to **Mark your current location**, using Siri, is following these few simple steps:

1. **Ask** Siri "**Where am I?**" or similar questions;
2. It will pop you up a preview of your location in Maps, **tap** on that **preview** to get into it;
3. **Tap** the **blue circle** (which represents you) and **tap** on **Mark my location**.

That's it, if you want to use Siri and a shortcut to get in Maps at your current location, this are the steps to follow.

---

In case you would prefer to directly **share** your location, you'll want to follow the same exact steps, except the last one, where you'll have to **Tap** on **Share my location**, rather than on Mark my location, and that's it.

Hope this helped you out!

Answer (score 1):

You can

- Install the Shortcuts app
- Search for “Share Location” in the Gallery
- Edit the shortcut, to send the location only to yourself.
- Disable “show when run” for the “Send” action.

Then “Siri, share my location” will (hands-free) send you a message with your current GPS coordinates.